# Adding images to horizontal paging UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to create a new user onboarding horizontal scroll view for an app in Swift 3.0.

I've managed to build out a set of 4 slides with page controls and a scroll view, with a very simple xib including a label, such that I can get my pages to scroll (across 4 slides) with a how-to step on each slide.

My code is below - as you can see with each slide the text is changing.

Now, I want to add images to these slides. I've added UIImageView to the xib, but I am not sure how to add them to the array that I've created here. Does anyone have advice? Thanks!

```
func createSlides() -> [Slide] {
    let slide1:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, option: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide1.label1.text = "Welcome to app!"

    let slide2:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide2.label1.text = "Browse for items"

    let slide3:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide3.label1.text = "Save your favorites"

    let slide4:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
    slide4.label1.text = "Share with friends"

return [slide1,slide2,slide3,slide4]

}
```

Comment: If you added a UIImageView variable to the slide class then you just set that variable. i.e. slide.imageView.image = <your image here>. You don't add the image to the array, you set it on the slide object you are adding to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you are setting `label1.text`.

First, you need to be sure your `UIImageView` object is linked to an `IBOutlet`, so you can access it via code. I'm assuming you already know how to do it, since you are access `label1` already.

Afterwards, just instantiate your `UIImage` like this:

```
slide1.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "tutorial1")
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - I understand this part, but I do not know how to set it on the slide object. Here is what I was trying ...  let slide1:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide {
        slide1.label1.text = "Welcome to app!"
        slide1.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"fireworks")
        }

Comment: "let declarations cannot be computed properties"

Comment: ah, so the problem is you are missing an `if` before your `let slide1: Slide...` and remove the exclamation mark from `as!`, make is `as?`

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you!  For my future reference .. what is the diff between ! and ?

Comment: `?` is an optional. `!` is a force unwrap of the optional value. If the value is `nil` it's going to crash. I suggest you taking some time to read Apple's iBook about Swift